# Basecamp Classic API cURL update multiple calendar entries

Tags: curl, basecamp

Cannot seem to update calendar entries from terminal with classic API.

This below currently gets me the xml for a specific calendar entry, but does not POST an  update successfully. I'm looking to update multiple calendar entries at one time if possible, or at least one at a time, successfully.

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -u "API token":X POST -d '<request><calendar-entry><all-day type="boolean">true</all-day><title>Stuff</title><due-at type="date">2012-07-09</due-at></calendar-entry></request>'
https://"domain".basecamphq.com/projects/"project#"/calendar_entries/"entry#".xml
```

I would like to thank you for suggestions in advance, it seems like this is the easiest way to get at basecamp without any wrappers.

Thanks

Comment: 37signals recommended PUT instead of POST, yet I still receive a 404

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, the verb PUT is to be used with HTTP, not POST and -X flag was missing, after coincidental X placeholder

And the flag -X was missing. This -X is required after the placeholder (apitoken):X.  Basecamp used X in documentation as a placeholder, but this character does not hold any significant value currently to authenticate the API call, yet represents potential for password and apitoken authetication at some point in the future possibly.

This is the cURL for individual calendar entry updates, as per the above question, to individual and pre-existing basecamp calendar entries:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -u "API token":X -X PUT -d '<request><calendar-entry><all-day type="boolean">true</all-day><title>Stuff</title><due-at type="date">2012-07-09</due-at></calendar-entry></request>'
https://"domain".basecamphq.com/projects/"project#"/calendar_entries/"entry#".xml
```